# How to obfuscate or scramble Wordpress production data

Tags: database, wordpress, security, development-environment, privacy

I'm managing a team of developers working remotely. The site is powered by Wordpress with an assortment of custom plugins. I have no problem distributing the source code for our site, but I'm very hesitant to start passing around the production data from the database, which includes user's names and emails, etc.

I know this is a common problem for developers trying to manage a production and development version of a project, so I thought there might be some common strategies out there. It even occurred to me that there might be some Wordpress-specific solutions, which would be even better. Any suggestions for how to handle this problem would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

"obfuscation"  or "scrambling"  or other methods of (in)[security though obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) is in no way shape or form a secure approach to any problem,  and this will always be true.

If you are worried about spilling password hashes to developers,  then don't use password hashes.  Use [Wordpress+Oauth](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/oauth) to authenticate.

If you are worried about developers getting other information, then give them a development database snapshot.

Comment: What is a development database snapshot? 

It's possible that I used the wrong terms in my question, but the goal is not website security. It's simply a question of how to allow outside developers to work on the project without distributing sensitive data.

Comment: It's outside the scope of this question, but I disagree that security through obscurity is not a secure approach "to any problem". It seems there are many low-stakes situations in which obscurity DOES provide an additional layer of security and is therefore worth doing. Changing the table prefixes on Wordpress site from the default wp_ is an example that comes to mind. Does it mean your db can never get hacked anyway? Of course not. But it does make it harder, so why not?